# Monitor.TryEnter just working the first time

Tags: c#, transactions, locking

I have a AddOn and it consumes a SAP Business One SDK. My AddOn have some Threads, each one have Transactions. SAP Business One SDK only accepted one Transaction by session, then I cant start a transaction if a Transaction in use.

Actually I have this control in StartTransaction method:

```
StarTransaction()
{
    if (!Monitor.TryEnter(syncRoot, new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 10)))
        throw new TimeoutException("Transaction is busy, Try Again in some seconds");

    mCompany.StartTransaction();
}

EndTransaction()
{
    try
    {
        mCompany.EndTransaction(endType);
    }
    finally
    {
        Monitor.Exit(syncRoot);
    }
}
```

In the screen, I have a catch with this command (Example):

```
catch (TimeoutException Ex)
{
    AddOn.Mensagens.ShowStatusBarMessage('Please, try again');
}
```

Actually this code works, but works only one time. 
After this message, I start the process again, and the message returned will the same '(Try again)'.

I'm using the wrong TryEnter or forgot to release something? I can not complete the transaction because another process might be using.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You need to provide a better code example. From the behavior, it's obvious that for some reason the `EndTransaction()` method is not being called, or it is called on the wrong thread. But there's not enough context here to understand why that would be. Note that you have to call `Monitor.Exit()` from the same thread that acquired the lock; many asynchronous APIs (possibly the one you're using here) will raise completion events in a different thread than where the operation was started. But you should be seeing an exception on the `Monitor.Exit()` if that were the case here.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to release lock. Should be something like

```
StarTransaction()
{
    if (!Monitor.TryEnter(syncRoot, new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 10)))
        throw new TimeoutException("Transaction is busy, Try Again in some seconds");
    // if we are here, then lock was successfully taken
    try
    {
        mCompany.StartTransaction();
    }
    finally
    {
        Monitor.Exit(syncRoot);
    }
}
```